# Consuming a WCF Service POST VIA REST calls with java

Tags: java, wcf, service

I have a WCF service up and running and can use get requests just fine.
But I'm not sure how to handle post this is the wcf service information

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/DeleteUser",
        Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    boolean DeleteMember(int customerID);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as straight forward as GET request but with message body having the customer id. I can give you more details if see your get request java code.

Comment: Thanks that comment helped out, the response was non standard because I had Bodystyle set to bare.